# How to use eglot to set analyze path for python project?

Tags: python, eglot

I'm trying to use eglot on gem5, but I've noticed that I need to specify the analysis directory as `src/python`, and I understand that it seems to be possible to set this by setting `eglot-workspace-configuration`, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can find [here](https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot/discussions/687), you can use 'project.el facilities' to set the root dir for an 'eglot project'. Then, the initial comment of the project.el file mentions that the VCS project type can also be used for 'non-VCS controlled directories' via the `project-vc-extra-root-markers` variable (refer to its docstring for more info).

So I would advise you to try creating a `.dir.locals.el` file in that src/python directory containing:

```lisp
((nil . ((project-vc-extra-root-markers ".dir-locals.el"))))
```

As you are creating the .dir-locals.el file anyway, you can also immediately use it as a `project-vc-extra-root-markers`, but you could use some other marker (i.e. filename in the src/python dir) also.

Now visit a file in the `src/python` directory and do `M-:` `(project-root)` to see if the new project root directory is recognized. If not, then try again after restarting Emacs (restarting will clear the `vc-file-prop-obarray` 'cache').

If the previous step returns the 'correct' project root dir, then start eglot. I hope now eglot indeed uses this project root as your 'analysis dir'. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I recently found out that in gem5 projects there are both cpp and python languages, and simply using `src/python` as the project directory causes clangd to fail, and I wanted to ask if there's any other way to make python lsp analyze only the `src/python` directory